# Parametric equation and distance formula

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

Help with this assignment! For the past three weeks now, I've been battling with mathematics assignment. I've successfully solved some but these ones posed a great challenge to me

1. Eliminate the parameter and identify the graph of the resulting equation

$x = 3v+7, y = v-1$

$x = \sin t, y = \cos t, 0\leq t \leq \pi$

$x = 3\sin t, y = 2\cos t, 0\leq t \leq \pi$

$x = 7u^2-3, y = 4-2u$

$x = 2+\cos t, y = 1+\sin t$

2. Prove that the distance between line $y = mx+c$ and the origin is given by $d = \frac{|c|}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$.
3. Use the above equation again to show that the distance between the line and the point $(x,y)$ is $d = \frac{|y-mx-c|}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$.

For question 1, I just need a hint to go about solving them since they are kinda similar. I seriously need help in question 2 and 3 because I'm lacking when its comes to proving or showing relation between one thing and another.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), the math templating system for this website. I've edited that into your question, along with cleaning up a few formatting issues to make the post display better.

Comment: Invaluable and thanks also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint for #2 and #3:

The distance between the line $y = mx+c$ and a point $(w,z)$ is defined as the minimum distance between any point $(x,y)$ on the line and the point $(w,z)$.

Using Euclidean distance (which I am assuming the question asks for), the distance between a point on the line and the point $(w,z)$ is:

$$d((x,y),(w,z)) = \sqrt{(x-w)^2 + (y-z)^2} = \sqrt{(x-w)^2 + (mx+c-z)^2}$$

So, you need to find the minimum value of that distance.

Hint for #1 (I'll just go ahead and do the first, which is the simplest):

Start by isolating the parameter $v$ in the first equation:
$$ v = \frac{x-7}{3}$$

Then, substitute into the second equation:

$$ y(x) = v - 1 = \frac{x-7}{3} - 1$$

The graph is the graph of y(x).

Comment: In the last equation I saw something like mx+b is subtituted for y instead of mx+c. Was that a typo error or sth otherwise?

Comment: That was a typo! Good catch.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Any hint on how to approach question 1. I'm thinking of making the common variable subject formula for each corresponding equation. Will it worth the effort?

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a hint for #1.

Answer (score 3):

$x = \sin t, y = \cos t, 0\leq t \leq \pi$

I would really hope that you just recognize this as a circle, as this is close to the unit circle definition of cosine and sine.

You could say:

$x^2 = \sin^2 t\\ y^2= \cos^2 t\\
x^2 + y^2 = \sin^2 t + \cos^2 t = 1$

Considering the limits on $t$ once that is applied, you will get a semi-circle.

Moving on to,

$x = 3\sin t, y = 2\cos t, 0\leq t \leq \pi$

That is just a circle with a dilation applied.

And using the same logic for the algebra.

$\frac {x}{3} = \sin t, \frac {y}{2} = \cos t\\
\frac {x^2}{9} + \frac {y^2}{4} = 1$

Regarding:

$x = 7u^2-3, y = 4-2u$

Isolate $u,$ and substitute.

$u = \frac {4-y}{2}\\
x = 7\frac {(4-y)^2}{4}-3$

And simplify.

As for $2, 3$ the distance between a point and a line, is the shortest distance.

I would start at the point (the origin in problem 2) and move along a line perpendicular to the targeted line, until I found the point of intersection.

$y = -\frac {1}{m} x$ is perpendicular to $y= mx + c$ and goes through the origin.

Now use substitution or elimination.

$(1+m^2) x + mc = 0\\
x = \frac {-mc}{1+m^2}\\
y = \frac {c}{1+m^2}$

$d((0,0),(x,y)) = \sqrt {x^2 + y^2} = \sqrt {\frac {c^2 + c^2m^2}{(1+m^2)^2}} = \frac {|c|}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}$

Comment: Million thanks. Your response is very much appreciated

Comment: #2 and #3 can also be done using calculus, differentiating the distance function with respect to $x$ to find the minimum. That is how I worked it out, I like your way too.

Comment: @AdamFrancey This is material that should be covered in pre-calc, and I would be hesitant to use calculus.